# Prove that $100|11^{10} - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization

I want to prove divisibility using factoring, So i need to show that $11^{10}-1$ can be written as prime factors of 100.

This is what I've tried:
$$11^{10}-1    $$ 
$$ (11^{5})^{2}-1$$
$$ (11^{5}-1)(11^{5}+1 )$$
$$10(11^{4}+11^{3}+11^{2}+11^1+1)(12)(11^4-11^3+11^2-11^1+1)$$
$$5*2^3*3[(11^4+11^2+1)+(11^3+11)]*[(11^4+11^2+1)-(11^3+11)]$$

I wanna write the $[(11^4+11^2+1)+(11^3+11)]*[(11^4+11^2+1)-(11^3+11)]$ as $5k$ with $k$ $\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I'd love any help/hint that would move me forward.

Comment: But you already solved it in the the 5th line. You have $5$ times $2$ times (something). (In fact, you solved it in the 4th line).

Comment: Wow, this question is closed as duplicate in just $121$ seconds.

Comment: @Yanko  Sorry I meant $100|11^{10} - 1$ not $10|11^{10} - 1$

Comment: I think you should ask a new question because now (after it's been marked as a duplicated answer) we are not able to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$11\equiv 1 \mod 10$$ so $$11^{10}\equiv 1^{10}\equiv 1 \mod 10$$